# C# HttpWebRequest Post Method many parameters in form

Tags: c#, .net, html, parameters, httpwebrequest

I am writing a simple C# program to do some web request and posting data.
I understand how the basics work like how to login with password and stuff of a html form.
However I am wondering if there is a lot of input parameters (such as this question page ) like check boxes and text fields, is there any efficient method than hard-coding 20 parameters in a string and passing it in?  I can read the html file parse it and scan out the input and use String builder to make such a string but I am wondering is there a more efficient method than doing that?

```
    private HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument getpage(string url ,String input)
    {
        try
        {
            Stream datastream;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            if (input!=null)
            {
                String postData = "";
                request.Method = "POST";
                if (input == "login")
                {
                    postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", "myusername", "mypassword");
                }
                else if (input == "sendMessage")
                {
                //THIS IS THE LONG STRING THAT I DON'T WANT TO HARD CODE
                    postData = String.Format("reciever={0}&sendmessage={1}", "thepersontomessage" ,this.DefaultMessage);
                //I am just puting two parameters for now, there should be alot
                }
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                datastream = request.GetRequestStream();
                datastream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                datastream.Close();
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
            String sourceCode = "";
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream))
            {
                sourceCode = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(sourceCode);
            this.cookies.Add(response.Cookies);
            return htmlDoc;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Also is there a simple way to see what are the parameter values set to when I click a button on a html form within a browser (basically the post url string and parameter values that is sent) so I can hardcode those values into the Postdatastring (check boxs, texts etc)

Comment: To see what a brower sends to a server, install [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com)

Answer (score 11):

Personally what I would do is build the parameters as a `Dictionary<string,string>` so that you can just do:

```
var parms = new Dictionary<string,string>();

parms.Add("username","fred");
```

You can then have a method such as:

```
string DictToString(Dictionary<string,string> dict)
{
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

   foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in dict) {
      builder.Append(kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value + "&");
   }

   return builder.ToString();
}
```

You can then get the final parameter string with:

```
var parms_str = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply , I don't know why anyone would downvote you for no apparent reason, but I guess to put the Key and value in the dictionary, I still have to parse the Html and get all the inputs from the form right? not other easier way?

Comment: You could use the same dictionary mentioned above, and then pass it in to WebClient.UploadValues(). that will format the FORM POST correctly for you. You dont have to create the query string yourself.

Comment: but what if one of the parameters is a file? should i convert it to byte[] and then to string?

Comment: @UrielArvizu No. This is simply for data sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you wanted to support files you'd probably need to use `multipart/form-data`.